# How do I change a text dictionary from file into usable dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, function, file, dictionary, text

Right so, I need to make this function that basically saves a player's username in a dictionary which is next saved in a text file to be reused again.

The problem is on reusing it I can't manage to get the str that I get from the file into a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
from ast import eval

def verification(j, d):
    if j in d.keys():
        return d
    else:
        d[j] = [0,0]
    return d

savefile = open("save.txt", "r")
'''d = dict()
for line in savefile:
    (key, val) = line.split(".")
    d[key] = val
print(d)'''
d = savefile.read()
python_dict = literal_eval(d)
savefile.close()


j = input("name? ")
result = verification(j, python_dict)

savefile = open("save.txt", "w")
'''for i in result:
    text = i + "." + str(result[i]) + " \n"
    savefile.write(text)'''
savefile.write(str(result))
savefile.close()
```

As you can see I tried with the `literal_eval` from `ast`. I also tried to do a .split() but that wouldn't work. So I'm stuck. Any ideas? It would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: "Wouldn't work"—please provide the full traceback. In general you should provide a [mcve], including the smallest input and code necessary to reproduce your problem—and what the actual problem is.

Comment: consider working with [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead

Comment: @Tomerikoo How would that look with my code?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Well I saved the keys and their value in the file that was separated by a "." and what would happen is that when I do a new line it would go down two. Therefore there would be an error because there isn't anything to split and make into a separate key and value

Comment: Did you have a look in that link? it is pretty much straightforward. As simple as `json.dump(result, savefile)` and `python_dict = json.load(savefile)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ah no, sorry I thought it was going to lead me to the json stack overflow page, thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do your own encoding/decoding from scratch when you have existing libraries to do it for you.

One good example is [`JSON`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) which is also not Python exclusive so the database you create can be used by other applications.

This can be done easily by:

```py
import json

def verification(j, d):
    if j not in d:
        d[j] = [0,0]
    return d

with open("save.txt", "r") as savefile:
    python_dict = json.load(savefile)

j = input("name? ")
result = verification(j, python_dict)

with open("save.txt", "w") as savefile:
    json.dump(result, savefile)
```

Comment: I ran your code and it gives me an error : after giving me 5 file paths it says this : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: As the error says, JSON uses double-quotes `"`. If you wrote the file manually, change the single ones to double

Comment: share the contents of the file

Comment: So I added the double quotes in the text and it works, apart from the fact that `python_dict` is a string and not a dictionary, therefore, I cannot add and change its keys and values.

Comment: The file contains : "{'Natsirt': [0, 0]}"

Comment: So just change it to `{"Natsirt": [0, 0]}`

Comment: I've done that and now it gives me this error: `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`. Think it could be because I have an input that puts the single quotes instead of double. I've tried converting `result` in string and it doesn't work

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Try to start off with the contents of the file as an empty dict `{}` and see what happens, because it works fine for me...

Comment: It's because I had replaced the w with an r. It works fine now, thanks a lot for your patience and time

Comment: Oh I see. No problem! Glad to help. Enjoy!